# What is a Node.js module?

Tags: node.js

What exactly is a Node.js module? To my understanding, there are modules which you can import from npm, but you can also create your own modules. Please explain so a beginner can understand.

Comment: It's a document that contains code, or sometimes many documents of related code.  An imported module is an abstraction of all the code in a document. e.g. `const a = require(./path/to/moduleName)` is the same as copying and pasting all the code from that module into your working document where the definition is being made.  You can then reference variables and function from that module using the abstraction `a.variableName`, `a.functionName`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A module is code in file or files which can be imported in your project and be used.
For instance, express is a popular web framework module which you can imported in your project by installing it via npm install command and then importing it in your code base via the require statement, and then using the functions provided by it. 
From Java perspective it will be a library/jar which you mark as a dependency and then import it in your project and use the functions provided by it.

Answer (score -1):

A module is a 'standardized part' of a system. It's a way to split up a large codebase into a manageable way. If you're familiar with OOP, consider modules being analogous to classes.